# Golang for loop inside for loop string operation taking abnormal time

Tags: go

Golang version : go version go1.13.5 windows/amd64

Please take a look at this code :

https://go.dev/play/p/pfqXLnuQfYA

When we run it on play then it is timing out.

In my local windows machine 16GB ram taking 50 seconds time.
Another unix machine 96GB ram taking 1minute 8 seconds time.

Another variation of same code taking more than 5 minutes https://go.dev/play/p/WMPvGYPSDjJ
While in java this program takes a minute only.

Please give pointers what is going wrong in this?
How come it is taking so much time ?

Comment: You are executing `47831 * 47831 = 2,287,804,561` iterations, where you create string values which you don't use, will be garbage collected. What do you expect? That it runs  under 100 ms? Btw, RAM size plays no role here, the created string values will not accumulate over time (due to garbage collection). If you want to measure (benchmark) `strings.ToLower()`, then use the testing framework and write proper benchmark functions.

Comment: P.S. Go 1.13.5 is ancient history. It's not supported anymore. Please use the latest 1.17 version which also contains numerous optimization.

Comment: @icza thanks for guidance, i tried function posted by Wolfgang answer that is also taking same time 50seconds on my machine...golang version upgrade will evaluate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @icza pointed out, you're creating strings that are not used and get garbage collected, additionally using an old version of Go.

This program runs in 6.3s in my machine with `go version go1.17.5 linux/amd64`

```
func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    log.Println("for loop started")
    a := make([]string, 0)
    a = append(a, "N")
    x := 0
    for i := 0; i < 47831; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 47831; j++ {
            a[0] = strings.ToLower(a[0])
            x++
        }
    }
    endTime := time.Now()
    log.Println("for loop end, time taken=", endTime.Sub(startTime), "iters=", x)
}

2021/12/20 10:26:22 for loop started
2021/12/20 10:26:29 for loop end, time taken= 6.323187151s iters= 2287804561
```

Comment: thanks for giving direction, i tried function posted in your answer that is also taking same time 50seconds on my machine...golang version upgrade will evaluate further.

Comment: i just tried above your given function on "go version go1.17.5 windows/amd64" 16gb ram, taking almost same time of 46seconds..will try further on UNIX machine to see if it matches your time of 6second.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @icza and answered by @Wolfgang, You can use latest version of Golang.

OR

If you want to make it fast then divide the task in different goroutines. It will definitely enhance the time.

These are the three factor due to which you are getting abnormal time.

At that time when the program started :

1. Number of process in the waiting queue irrespective of the OS.
2. CPU scheduling
3. Clock speed of processor